# Expand() with more than one Where condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, lambda

In my Application I have below tables:

```
return (
  (
    from o in ctxImport.TableA.Expand("TableD/TableC,TableD/TableB") 
    where o.TableAID == ID select o
  ) as DataServiceQuery<DataService.TableA>
);
```

Here TableA, TableB, TableC are parent tables. TableD is mapping table between these 3 tables.

Above code is only having where condition on TableA primary key. I need to add one more where condition in above for TableB primary key.

Output list should be same.

`ctxImport` is the object of the database entity.

Can you please help me on these problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
from o in ctxImport.TableA.Expand("TableD/TableC,TableD/TableB") 
where o.TableAID == ID select o
   && o.TableD.Any(d => d.TableB.Any(b => b.Id == condition))
```

assuming that `TableD` and `TableB` are collection navigation properties.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I got an exception like Any is not supported. I resolved the problem in different way. I expanded the TableD.

Comment: It is supported in WCF data services 5.0 (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/odatateam/archive/2012/04/09/wcf-data-services-5-0-rtm-release.aspx)